# Mapping different data frames based on multiple conditions in pandas df

Tags: pandas, dataframe, mapping

I have a df where I need to generate a column based on some conditions.

Sample_df

```
No.        Value1          Value2
1          AS              DS
2          AS              BS
3          Product         -
4                          AS
5          Tactical        VS
```

I have 2 more df which have values and I want to map it in.

The other df look like:
df2

```
Value1          Num
AS              Des
AS              Des
Product         P
```

df3

```
Value2 Num
DS     Des
AS     Bed
BS     Ged
VS     Vis
```

Rule:
in Sample_df, column value1 should map all the values from df2 but if the **tactical** comes then it should use value2 df to map the values.

```
Desired Output
No.        Value1          Value2        NewCol
1          AS              DS            Des
2          AS              BS            Des
3          Product         -             P
4                          AS            -
5          Tactical        VS            Vis
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.apply` from pandas to achieve this alongside with conditional lambda statement.

I have implemented a helper function `conditional` just because some of the things don't have corresponding mappings, as well as multiple mappings which makes a little funky behavior

```py
import pandas as pd

def conditional(r):
  if isinstance(r,pd.Series) and r.size == 0:
    return '-' 
  else:
    if r.size > 1:
      return r.at[0]
    else: 
      return r.tolist()[0]

Sample_df['Value3'] = Sample_df.apply(lambda row: conditional(df2.loc[df2['Value1'] == row.Value1]['Num'])
                        if row.Value1 != 'Tactical' 
                        else conditional(df3.loc[df3['Value2'] == row.Value2]['Num']), axis = 1)
```

The provided code does just add a column on to your original DataFrame, if you didn't want that, you can just first copy and then apply.

```py
from copy import copy
new_df = copy(Sample_df)
new_df['Value3'] = Sample_df.apply(lambda row: conditional(df2.loc[df2['Value1'] == row.Value1]['Num'])
                        if row.Value1 != 'Tactical' 
                        else conditional(df3.loc[df3['Value2'] == row.Value2]['Num']), axis = 1)
```

output gained:

```
1   AS          DS  Des
2   AS          DS  Des
3   Product     -   P
4               AS  -
5   Tactical    VS  Vis
```